# Retrieve google user from ios extension

Tags: ios, google-signin, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I am trying to create a share extension for my application which requires to login to Google from the extension. I've setup the sharing group keychain and am able to write from the main application and read the extension target. But I can't login to Google from the extension because `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()` always returns false.

Is there any way to login to Google from an extension and how do I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to go with Action extension you can't do that in Share- extension  There are some restrictions for extensions Please refer this link----http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626898/scan-functionality-doesnt-work-on-action-extensionno-camera-opening-to-scan

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure. The only thing here is how google framework handle the keychain. But I will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer until now. I finally rewrite the Google login by using [Aerogear framework](https://aerogear.org/index.html). Now I can able to login from both main target and extension target. This also fix this [google logout issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/27).

Answer (score 6):

## 1. In Bridging-Header.h

```
import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
import <Google/Core.h>
```

## 2. In AppDelegate.swift

```
import Google
```

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchOptions:` configure the `GGLContext` object:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "client id"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}
```

Then, add a `GIDSignInButton` view to your app.

Lastly, in the view controller, implement the `signIn:didSignInForUser:` delegate method that will be called when the sign-in button is `tapped:` when authorizing the app.

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
    didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
           withError:(NSError *)error {
  // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
  // ...
}
```

## 3. Sharing Credentials between apps/extensions

When you sign-in the Google framework will have to use native iOS methods to add the new credentials to the iOS Keychain. Thus they will be using the `SecItemAdd(_:_:)` method that will add one or more items to a keychain.

To access the same keychain item in both the app and the extension, you need to enable the "Keychain Sharing" for both the app and the extension from the [Xcode's Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW15) section in your project settings. When you do this, Xcode will probably want to update your app ID and provisioning profiles, because they need to reflect this new capability. You'll probably have to reauthorize the app *(Step 2)* to get the credentials into the right group.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemAdd) clearly states:

> If you want the new keychain item to be shared among multiple
>   applications, include the kSecAttrAccessGroup key in the attributes
>   dictionary. The value of this key must be the name of a keychain
>   access group to which all of the programs that will share this item
>   belong.
>
> When you use Xcode to create an application, Xcode adds an
>   *application-identifier* entitlement to the application bundle. Keychain
>   Services uses this entitlement to grant the application access to its
>   own keychain items. You can also add a *keychain-access-groups*
>   entitlement to the application and, in the entitlement property list
>   file, specify an array of keychain access groups to which the
>   application belongs.

## 4. Extra Hints from Google that I haven't mentioned above.

Please see ["Google Sign-In for iOS"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios).
Here is sample code to use `GIDSignIn`:

1. Get a reference to the `GIDSignIn` shared instance: `GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];`
2. **Set the OAuth 2.0 scopes you want to request: `[signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]];`**
3. Call `[signIn setDelegate:self];`
4. Set up delegate method `signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:`.
5. **Call `handleURL` on the shared instance from `application:openUrl:`... in your app delegate.**
6. Call `signIn` on the shared instance;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the section 3 is not relevant. I did enable sharing keychain but the problem is that GIDSignIn somehow doesn't have credential in the share extension. Is there anyway to overwrite the keychain behaviour of GIDSignIn?

Comment: There is a way if you plan on using Google Plus Sign In instead of Google Sign In. GPPSignIn saves the credentials in the keychain but you can call .keychainName in both the extension and the app to specify the same group you want to retrieve the credentials from. Anyhow, to refresh the token and give access to the extension you need to call the signInSilently (or it's equivalent in GPPSignIn). I'll let you know if I find anything else specific to GIDSIgnIn.

Comment: With GIDSignIn I can use this `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().setValue(kGoogleClientKeychainname, forKey: "_keychainName") //GIDSignIn._keychainName`. But it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Also Google+ SignIn is deprecated @sahara108, See https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: is keychain sharing still an option since GIDSignIn 5.0.0? GIDSignIn doesn't seem to write to keychain or at least specify it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to enable `Keychain Sharing` in your project's "Capabilities" pane. This will allow both the extension and the main app to share the password.

Apple's documentation on Keychain Sharing is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW15).